# IE not working Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet, internet-explorer

I'm using windows 7 and I am connected to wifi for my internet. At the moment, my skype is working but IE is unable to do any kind of browsing. I'm unable to understand what is issue. I tried chromo to and it is also not working.

Can anyone please help me fix this issue?

when i try to ping `www.yahoo.com` from `cmd` i get following message:

```
C:\Users\alpha>ping www.yahoo.com
```

> Ping request could not find host www.yahoo.com. Please check the name and try ag
>   ain.

Comment: Your DNS is probably not working. Since you've not described your network infrastructure, that's the best I can do.

Comment: Please tell me how can i describe what you want? how can i give you information? any cmd command?

Comment: What Internet connection do you have? Are you using a router or is this at work? How long has this problem been happening? What is new in your environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was related to DNS Server. I just executed following commands and it was working again:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

after restart my internet was working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect any one of below scenario might caused,

- You might have working on proxy servers
- Your network got disconnected

Try below steps to make it working:-

- Shutdown your laptop
- Switch off modem and router
- Give some 2 minutes gap
- Start modem and router
- Once connected, Switch On the laptop
- Try accessing **`www.google.com`**